# Show comments only to author and admins

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to restrict a user so that they only see their own comments along with any admin user replies and for the admin user to see all users comments?

The user should also be able to edit their own comments.

I am trying to use sessions to do that.......but unable to achieve how can do using session by retrieving `user_id` of particular current user in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you can get current users data with function wp_get_current_user();
check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user .

To restict user to view only his/her comments, you have to alter wordpress's theme's comments.php file.